# Transform multidimensional array structure

Tags: php, arrays

I've been given an array with some date from a mySQL consultation. However, the data is in the following format:

```
Array (   
[ano_quarantine] => Array ( [0] => 2020 [1] => 2019 [2] => 2018 [3] => 2017 [4] => 2016 )  
[quarantine] => Array ( [0] => 61 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [4] => 2 ) )
```

Is there any way to change the array to the following structure?

```
Array (   
0: {ano_quarantine: "2020", quarantine: 61}   
1: {ano_quarantine: "2019", quarantine: 1}   
2: {ano_quarantine: "2018", quarantine: 1}  
3: {ano_quarantine: "2017", quarantine: 2}
4: {ano_quarantine: "2016", quarantine: 2}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone for a generic solution in case your input data can vary in the number of sets of values. You can find all the keys of the array with `array_keys`, then iterate over the keys of the first subarray, combining the keys of the outer array with each of the columns of the array indexed by that key:

```
$result = array();
$keys = array_keys($array);
foreach (array_keys($array[$keys[0]]) as $key) {
    $result[] = array_combine($keys, array_column($array, $key));
}
print_r($result);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ano_quarantine] => 2020
            [quarantine] => 61
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ano_quarantine] => 2019
            [quarantine] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ano_quarantine] => 2018
            [quarantine] => 1
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [ano_quarantine] => 2017
            [quarantine] => 2
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [ano_quarantine] => 2016
            [quarantine] => 2
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/oAs9c)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a merge function or you can use a for to assign the values of both fields to a new array with fields "ano_quarantine" and "quarantine".